# Why isn't Node included as a dependency for Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am learning Express and I see that per the docs it contains some of the same functionality as Node.  For example, request and response are said to be the exact same as Node.

See here:
https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html

If Node is not included as a dependency can I assume that they are using a fork from the Node project?

No mention of Node here in the **package.json**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "config": "^1.29.4",
    ...  snip
    "style-loader": "^0.19.1",
    "yarn": "^1.5.1"
  },
```

Comment: Node isn't a package you install as a dependency of Express. It's the runtime that provides the environment and the javascript engine.

Comment: node is built into node.js, no need to declare the depends.

Answer (score 2):

Node isn't an NPM package, it's the thing that runs Node modules, so it wouldn't be listed under package dependencies.

Specific versions of Node could be listed under [the engines key](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#engines), if the package chooses to specify required Node versions to run it. This is optional information however.

Answer (score 1):

I think the confusion comes from many developers interchangeably calling many apps and APIs "Node Application" or "Express Application".

I believe this is due to overwhelming amount of NodeJS server applications that use express as a package.

Answer (score 0):

Express is a node.js package, which you probably installed using npm (node package manager). See their getting started: installation (https://expressjs.com/en/starter/installing.html) which installs express through npm. Node.js is an environment for server side javascript, and express is library for node.js.